# What can I use alternative to AJP connector?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, jboss, ajp

My Application is having apache-jboss connection using AJP connector.

This is code snippets of JBoss standalone-full.xml

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

But I am facing one issue with it. I can see there are many AJP threads are in RUNNABLE state in thread dumps which is consuming memory and it is increasing in number.

```
"ajp-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-38000-179" daemon prio=3 tid=0x02a6ac00 nid=0x44e runnable [0x903ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:1131)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:1213)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:451)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can you please suggest what is the reason behind it?

### Additional information

Apache - apache-2.2.29
Jboss - jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

If I will look for other connector then what are other protocol that I can use?